# Random Set of Dates for Laravel Project

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

This is a Laravel project that I'm attempting to get a random collection of dates between the two dates below. The random dates chosen need to be 6 years apart and be on either a Monday, Thursday or Sunday. I have the dates function below that works for another date range I need however with this situation there's the additional factor of 6 years so I need the additional modification for it and not sure what I need to do to account for it on this situation.

```
$start = Carbon::parse('First Monday of January 2000');
$nextMonth = Carbon::now()->addMonth();

collect([
    'monday' => false,
    'thursday' => false,
    'sunday' => true
])->flatMap(function ($bool, $day) use ($start, $nextMonth) {
    return dates($start, $nextMonth, $day, $bool);
})->sort(function ($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);
})->values()->map(function ($date, $key) {
        return factory(Event::class)->create([
            'name' => 'Event ' . ($key + 1),
            'date' => $date
        ]);
})->filter(function ($event) {
        return $event->date->lt(Carbon::today());

function dates(Carbon $from, Carbon $to, $day, $last = false)
{
    $step = $from->copy()->startOfMonth();
    $modification = sprintf($last ? 'last %s of next month' : 'next %s', $day);

    $dates = [];
    while ($step->modify($modification)->lte($to)) {
        if ($step->lt($from)) {
            continue;
        }

        $dates[$step->timestamp] = $step->copy();
    }

    return $dates;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify a list of preferred dates, eg: Monday Jan 1 2000, Thursday March 12 2006, Sunday June 24 2012 or 2006,2007,2008.. etc?

Answer (score 2):

If the second date is ***exactly*** six years from the first random date:

`$second_date = $first_date->diffInYears($first_date->copy()->addYears(6))`

From Carbon docs:  http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference

**Update:**

Here is a way of creating an array of dates, based on a start date, where each date is at least six years apart and either a Monday, Thursday or Sunday.

I've left the loop at 20 iterations so you can see the dates generated are different days over the years.

```
$start = Carbon::parse('First Monday of January 2000');

$dates = array();

for ($i = 1; $i < 20; $i ++)
{
    $interval = $i * 6;
    if ($start->copy()->addYears($interval)->dayOfWeek === Carbon::MONDAY OR $start->copy()->addYears($interval)->dayOfWeek === Carbon::THURSDAY OR $start->copy()->addYears($interval)->dayOfWeek === Carbon::SUNDAY)
    {
        $dates[] = $start->copy()->addYears($interval);
    } else
    {
        $dates[] = $start->copy()->addYears($interval)->modify('next monday');
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have a $first_date variable.

Comment: This was just an example to show the methods of diffInYears() and addYears().  Can you explain what you need to achieve?  It doesn't sound like you want truly random dates, is that right?

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is having 4 events created initially, however, a new event needs to be created every 6 years, however it has to be created on a Monday, Thursday, or Sunday. The date doesn't have to be exactly every 6 years but at minimum 6 years.

Comment: Any further ideas for this?

Comment: I've added an example of creating an array of dates with your requirements

Comment: Where do you get the 20 and 6 integers from?

Comment: The 6 is because you need the dates to be six years apart.  The 20 is how many dates you need in an array.  I think you said you only needed four, but as the first four all happened to be a Monday, I increased it to 20 to show that the date could be either a Monday, Thursday or Sunday.  If you change the 20 back to 4, you will have the array of the dates of your 4 events.